# Что со шрифтом на Opera ?

Tags: opera, html, css, шрифты

Здравствуйте. Подключил шрифт "Play" с GoogleFonts. На всех броузерах кроме оперы все отлично.

На Opera будто не работает сглаживание.

[image]

Есть варианты как это поправить?

[Большая картинка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3sLR.png)

Comment: Что ты хотел. Это же опера хD

Comment: Это ж у вас подключены не стандартные шрифты? Попробуйте добавить свойство: **text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;** Еще можно попробовать поиграться с таким свойством: **-webkit-font-smoothing:**, установив значение или **antialiased**, или **subpixel-antialiased**.

Comment: @Deonis, webkit-font-smoothing никак не влияет :( В хроме все отлично и он тоже на вебките.. наверное придется дропать эти шрифты.

Comment: @wwvv, со шрифтами особо не поборешься. Можно еще добавить **text-shadow** для того, что как-то сгладить, но это, пожалуй, ситуацию не очень спасет.

Comment: попробуй скачать этот шрифт и подключить формат otf и только его. Ну и для ослика eot на всякий пожарный. Хотя я замечал, что последние ослики otf также понимают

Answer (score 2):

Это косяк с субпиксельным сглаживанием. Часто помогает поиграть размером шрифта на 1-2 пиксела в обе стороны